# laravel 5 GuzzleHttp Client https cURL error 35

Tags: php, laravel, ssl

I am using the GuzzleHttp in laravel 5.
was to be connected to https://my-site.com/xxxx/, but it does not lead well.

```
$client = new Client();

$urlTabinfo = 'https://my-site.com/api/xxxxx/';
$option['login'] = array('id'=>'aaa','pass'=>'xxxx');

$response = $client->post(
                     $urlTabinfo,
                     array('body' => $option));
```

When you post, an exception is raised.

Message is as follows.

```
cURL error 35: See http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html
```

You're running on FreeBSD,
/usr/local/share/certs/ca-root-nss.crt there a.

In addition, I ran the following curl command on the OS.
The result is as follows.

```
% Curl -k -vvv https://my-site.com
  :
  :
curl: (35) error: 14077458: SSL routines: SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO: reason (1112)

% Curl -k -3 -vvv https://my-site.com
  :
```

: 
    * SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1)

Something, and I feel that needs to be set, but do not know well.

It can be seen better, please let me know.

Comment: Not sure, about this but there might be a problem with your SSL connection.From [libcurl errors page](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html):
**CURLE_SSL_CONNECT_ERROR (35) :
A problem occurred somewhere in the SSL/TLS handshake. You really want the error buffer and read the message there as it pinpoints the problem slightly more. Could be certificates (file formats, paths, permissions), passwords, and others.**

Comment: Although I user name and password are correct. . .

Comment: That error indicates that there might be something wrong with SSL/TSL handshake. Are you trying to connect using https? Do you have the right permissions? Do you have the required certificates?